# Setting small and large icon in Visual C++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I am porting an old (Visual Studio 6.0) application to Visual Studio 2012 in order to add some enhancements. The application's icon in the resources view clearly has 2 versions of the icon, a 32x32 4bit bitmap and a 16x16 4bit bitmap.

In the main AppDlg.cpp there are 2 calls to `SetIcon()` as follows (created by default by MFC app wizard):

```
SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon
```

However, the icon displayed in the top left corner of the application's dialog window is the larger one, scaled down to 16x16 instead of the small one. Its also happening for the icon shown in the system tray.

It seems it uses the correct small one for the executable file when viewing it in Windows Explorer (detailed view / list view). So it is picking the small one in some circumstances.

How do I make it choose the smaller 16x16 icon for the top left corner of the dialog box and System tray?

Comment: Um, if that's really your code, then you're using the same icon for both large and small. From your description, it looks like `m_hIcon` is a large icon, so you're setting a large icon as your small icon, which will naturally result in scaling.

Comment: No it has a small icon and large icon in it. As I said the small icon is in fact used when listing the executable file in windows explorer detailed/list view, so it is there and picking it up in certain circumstances.

Comment: A single `HICON` cannot have both a small icon and a large icon in it. It is either one or the other. The icon directory has both large and small icons (and Explorer uses the icon directory), but an icon is a specific size.

Comment: Em, not really. Maybe we're not referring to the same thing, but an Icon resource can have multiple sizes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997538.aspx In fact I used the answer @cha suggested below and it worked and it is now showing the other icon correctly. The only issue I have left is the tray icon.

Comment: An icon resource is actually an icon directory. When you call `LoadIcon`, the icon directory is searched and a single image is taken. That single image is returned as the `HICON`. It's confusing.

Comment: Its confusing, agreed :). Any idea how to specifically load the small icon from the icon resource then? I think if I manage to do that I would be able to pass it to the `NOTIFYICONDATA.hIcon` and have the small one used for the system tray too.

Comment: The LoadImage function lets you specify what size you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Known Microsoft bug. See [this](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/281327-seticon-bug) discussion. (if you do not want to read, just comment out SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE) line and you'll be fine). Please note, that SetIcon only sets the icon on the dialog title bar (small icon) and when you use Alt-tab (big icon)

The icons you see in the Windows Explorer are the main Application Icons (the icon with the lowest ID in you rc file). It has nothing to do with the main dialog's SetIcon() method

The icon in the System Tray is something completely different. Normally, you would use Shell_NotifyIcon API to set the icon, but I bet your project would have a helper class that sets the icon [CSystemTray](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/74/Adding-Icons-to-the-System-Tray) by Chris Maunder is a popular one used by many programmers. Just search for Shell_NotifyIcon in your program to find out exactly what resource is used for the system tray icon

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I commented out `SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE)` but it didn't work, however when I commented out `SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE)` it worked. Regarding the tray icon, I am not using `CSystemTray` (I did this code ages ago before the time of this article :)). As you said I have a call to `::Shell_NotifyIcon()` and it takes a `NOTIFYICONDATA` which has a member called `hIcon`. I am just setting it to `GetIcon(TRUE)`. I tried changing it to `GetIcon(FALSE)` but instead the program disappears without setting the icon (maybe because I disabled `SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE)` for the other issue).

Comment: In order to load the small icon from the application's main icon this line does the trick: `HICON hTrayIcon = (HICON)LoadImage(
                AfxGetInstanceHandle(),
                MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MAINFRAME),
                IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, LR_SHARED );` and the `hTrayIcon` can then be used for the system tray.